# A thread fails to update the image as expected

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am trying to write a Delphi code to update the TImage components on a from. I was using C++ for long time but don't have much experience in Delphi;however, I need to use Delphi for some reason. I obtained and modified a similar code to do the task as shown as follows. I have 4 TImages components placed on a form, I start a thread to update the images when the player press the button. I have 6 resource bitmaps with numbered in 1 to 6  embedded in the project and the code will randomly pick and load the resource bitmap into the TImage. I find that using the thread sometimes, some images will not be drawn (just blank like no image being loaded). I know you may be wondering why I need to use a thread and why not just call ShowRanodmImage when the button is pressed. In this simple case, surely I don't have to use thread instead but I am going to apply to some situation that threading must be used. So my question is why the following code will occationally not show the proper image? How to fix that? Thanks a lot.

```
unit TTUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TTestThread = class;

  TTestForm = class(TForm)
    NextBTN: TButton;
    P11: TPanel;
    P12: TPanel;
    P13: TPanel;
    P14: TPanel;
    CELL11: TImage;
    CELL12: TImage;
    CELL22: TImage;
    CELL21: TImage;

    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure NextBTNClick(Sender: TObject);

  private
    myThread :TTestThread;
    pImgs: array[1..2, 1..2] of TImage;

  public
    procedure ShowRandomImg;
  end;

  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    myForm :TTestForm;
  protected
    procedure Execute(); override;
  public
    constructor Create(aFrom :TTestForm; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  end;

var
  TestForm: TTestForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTestForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myThread := TTestThread.Create(Self, True);

  pImgs[1][1]:=CELL11; pImgs[1][2]:=CELL12;
  pImgs[2][1]:=CELL21; pImgs[2][2]:=CELL22;
end;


procedure TTestForm.NextBTNClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TTestForm.ShowRandomImg;
var
 i, j :Integer;
 r :array[1..2, 1..2]  of Integer;
begin
  Self.NextBTN.Enabled := false;
  r[1][1] := Random(6)+1;
  r[1][2] := Random(6)+1;
  r[2][1] := Random(6)+1;
  r[2][2] := Random(6)+1;
  for i := 1 to 2 do
  begin
    for j := 1 to 2 do
    begin
      pImgs[i][j].Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceID(HInstance, r[i][j]);
      pImgs[i][j].Canvas.Font.Size := 38;
      pImgs[i][j].Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      pImgs[i][j].Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
      pImgs[i][j].Canvas.TextOut(20, 20, inttostr(r[i][j]));
    end;
  end;
  Self.NextBTN.Enabled := true;
end;

////////////////////
constructor TTestThread.Create(aFrom: TTestForm; CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  Self.myForm := aFrom;
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Repeat
    Self.myForm.ShowRandomImg;
    Self.Suspend;
  Until Terminated;

end;
end.
```

Comment: VCL is not thread-safe. You should ***never*** attempt to work with the UI main thread from within another thread. This needs to be synchronized so that all UI interaction happens within the main thread only. I suggest you study threads very carefully before attempting this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It seems ok if I wrap the ShowRandomImg with Synchronize(). I will take your suggestion to read something more the threading in Delphi also.

Comment: The basic rule is that the thread should be entirely self-contained and unaware of the UI. The Thread should only trigger synchronized events which inform the owner (in this case your form) that it needs to be updated. As practice, I suggest moving the thread to a separate unit of its own, and make sure this thread unit doesn't even use the form unit.

Comment: @user If you do that, what's the point of the thread? All the code is running in the main thread and your thread just provides needless overhead. What's more you must not call Resume or Suspend. If you do ever need to wait then use an event.

Comment: David has a good point, what you are trying to do makes the thread completely useless - because all it's doing is UI interaction. I say drop the thread completely. You don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Actually, the code I show is just partially functional. I need the thread because when I complete the code, I need to run some tedious calculation which is independent of the UI. The question I am asking there is about how the thread should be taken care to work with GUI. I think all you have already given me some ideas. Thanks again.

Comment: I spent some times to do some research on threading. The more I read, the more I got lost. Let's say I need to start some heavy duty when I press a button. The task needed to be run by a thread since it could take any time from 30 seconds to 2 minutes to finish, but any time in the midway when I the user click the button again, it has to terminate the task and close the app. So how to use threads and VCL to deal with something like that?

Comment: Without knowing what "task" your thread needs to do, or seeing your full code, I can't say. Your question as it stands does not contain enough information for anyone to help with your issue (which came later in the comments).